# Awk merging of two files on id

Tags: awk, merge

I would like to obtain the match the IDs of the first file to the IDs of the second file, so i get, for example, `Thijs Al,NED19800616,39`. I know this should be possible with AWK, but I'm not really good at it.

file1 (few entries)

```
NED19800616,Thijs Al
BEL19951212,Nicolas Cleppe
BEL19950419,Ben Boes
FRA19900221,Arnaud Jouffroy
...
```

file2 (many entries)

```
38,FRA19920611
39,NED19800616
40,BEL19931210
41,NED19751211
...
```

Comment: is the `ID` unique in either file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `awk`, use `join`.  First make sure the input files are sorted:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 file1 > file1.sorted
sort -t, -k2,2 file2 > file2.sorted
join -t, -1 1 -2 2 file[12].sorted
```

Answer (score 3):

With awk you can do

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print $2, $1, a[$1] }' OFS=, file2 file1
Thijs Al,NED19800616,39
Nicolas Cleppe,BEL19951212,
Ben Boes,BEL19950419,
Arnaud Jouffroy,FRA19900221,
```